# Recuperar variável do laço FOR dentro de um FOREACH - php

Tags: php, foreach, for

Oi, eu tenho dois laços na estrutura do meu código. O primeiro é um FOR que monta um array com dados. E tenho um foreach que percorre uns dados do BD.

Eu quero utilizar a variável que retorna no FOR e usar no foreach, mas parece que não tá rolando.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
for($i=0 ; $i < $contador; $i++)
{
    $tbnewsletterNews = Doctrine_Core::getTable('tbnews')->createQuery('a')->select('a.*')->where('a.id = ?', $param['id_noticia'][$i])->execute();
    foreach($tbnewsletterNews as $news) 
    {
      if($news->getImagem() !== '')
      {
        $noticias[] = '<div class="col-md-9" style="display:block; width:670px; margin-left:15px;"> </div>';
      }else{
       $noticias[] =  '<div class="col-md-9" style="display:block; width:670px; margin-left:15px;"> </div>';
      }
    }
  $body .= '<div class="col-md-12 col-noticias">'. $noticias[$i] . '</div> ';
} 

    foreach ($usuarios as $usuario)
    {

     $corpo = '<img src="http://www.meusite.gov.br/images/informativoHeader.jpg" width="700" height="175" border="0" style="margin:0; margin-bottom:15px;"/><br><br>
                '.$body.'
                <img src="http://www.meusite.gov.br/images/rodape.jpg" border="0"/>'.$sair;
    }
```

Eu quero usar é aquela variavel $body ali, mas quando salvo no banco o conteúdo dela está vazia :T

Comment: Não tem nada errado no código, pelo menos que dê para ver de cara. Pode ser que tenha algo errado com os dados e a variável esteja vazia. Pelo menos o problema não parece ser o que está descrito na pergunta. No primeiro bloco, a lógica de adicionar elementos ao *array* e depois acessar uma posição específica está estranha, era isto mesmo que queria?

Comment: Primeiro, como você inicializa a variável body? Porque ali no código aparece um trecho de código html sendo concatenada a ela. Outra coisa: se você realmente deseja salvar html no banco de dados você precisa você precisa codificar ele. Tente utilizar o método `htmlspecialchars()` para codificar antes de salvar no banco de dados e o método `htmlspecialchars_decode()` para decodificar posteriormente.

Comment: sim é bem isso, essa lógica já está funcionando em produção, mas agora eu tenho que gravar os dados no banco ao invés de enviar um e-mail (como está funcionando agora). Agora em produção eu consigo buscar a variável $body dentro do foreach, mas agora não funciona mais, hum.

Comment: Então o problema está em outro ponto que não está postado.

Comment: @EstácioDiFabio se você der um `print_r($body)` depois do for o que retorna?

Comment: a variavél $body é iniciada e setada ao mesmo tempo, logo apos o foreach do for ali.

Comment: O problema era que a variavel $contador estava comentada e eu nem vi. Agora está tudo certo.